# Email Program not working in Perl

Tags: perl

I was playing around in Perl and I wrote a small email program.  It went like this:

```
# -w
#the purpose of this program is to send an email .
print "Hello. Welcome to Paramjot's Mail Program. Please enter your name.\n";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp ($name);
print "Hello, $name. Please type in the email address you wish to send your email to\n";
$mailadds = <STDIN>;
chomp ($mailadds);              
open  MAIL, "|mail $mailadds";
print "Please type the message you wish to send below.\n";
$message = <STDIN>;
chomp ($message); 
print MAIL "$name says: $message";
close MAIL;
```

For some reason, when I run the program, it works until the program is supposed to ask for the message and instead says

```
mail is not recognized as a batch file, internal or external command, or an application.
```

What do I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Your `open` statement is the kind of thing I'd expect to see on a *nix box, but the error message smells of MS Windows.  Are you sure you really want to avoid using any of the Mail/SMTP modules?

Comment: How would I replace the open statement with something more windows's friendly?

Comment: try `MIME::Lite`, `Net::SMTP` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is coming from your operating system, not from Perl.

Your `open` statement attempts to start up a new process running the command `mail $mailadds`, but this fails because the operating system doesn't recognize the command `mail`.  To resolve the immediate error, you need to verify that `mail` (or an equivalent program) is installed on your computer and change the `open` statement to provide the full path and correct filename to that program.

The better solution to the overall task is to get a mail-handling module from CPAN and use that instead of calling an external program.  Such modules provide a friendlier interface, plus they often abstract away any operating-system-specific details, like determining the correct name and location of the program used to send mail.

Personally, I tend to use [MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aLite) for this, although the module's maintainer advises against using it.  The linked documentation includes suggestions of mail-sending modules that he considers to be "better alternatives" if you choose to heed his advice and not use MIME::Lite.